# Update a single property with REST/RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

What is the best way to update a single property with RestController?

I have a DTO with a lot of fields and need to update just one. Basically, on the frontend there might be no DTO at all. For example, frontend has 2 fields: username and birthday, both could be filled manually. On submit, on the server side, I need to find a user with that name and update that field. Despite the "lost update" problem, which is irrelevant in this case, what is the best way to accomplish that?

I see following options (assuming entity is identified by the path, like "/users/name"):

1. To pass json with PUT and just one required field set, i. e. `{ 'birthdate' : '1854/12/02'}` and to map it to the DTO class instance. It could be problematic, cause DTO could have some mandatory fields, like Id or something, which could break the whole design
2. To find whole entity/DTO from the client' side first, then to transfer it to the client, then modify, then pass it back to the RestController's PUT endpoint. Quite complicated for such a trivial operation.
3. To do everything manually, like, to use the same simple JSON with just this one field, and to parse JSON manually. To find/create entity/DTO in the service or controller then, and update. In this case, from my point of view, it's not good to manually parse body and the rest of manual work don't suit the whole spring/rest design.

I suppose, there's a simple and elegant way to achieve that. Please share. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is partial update. The correct way to do this is :

1. In the backend you expose an endpoint such as:

   PATCH /users/{id}
2. You can use an existing DTO but you need to make sure that the no fields are mandatory since then you break the "partial" thingy.. e.g PatchUserDTO.class
3. The request you will send:
   Body:
   {
   "name":"...",
   "birthday":"...."
   }
4. You find the entity by id provided in the path.
5. You map the fields from the dto to the existing entity.( You can use ModelMapper or just provide helper methods )
6. Pass down the model to the service layer and it takes care of saving etc..

You said that the resource can be identified by /users/name.. But this looks wrong because chances of names being unique are quite low..
Do not be afraid to have DTO's for specific use cases, you will have more classes but your code is more readable and you separate the concerns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regarding the name - it's just an example. Consider, it's an email or id or whatever. So, you think the 1) is the most suitable. But what about my doubts stated there? Like, making mandatory DTO fields not mandatory would break the design?

Regarding specific DTOs - yes, I thought to make specific DTO identical to the main one but without mandatory fields, but in case data model changes, all of them should be located and updated then.

Comment: As you already know, in SE its all about trade offs. If you want to keep the design more consistent, then you need to force the frontend to always provide everything that is needed and then you can do a complete update with PUT. In this case you could reuse one DTO for POST, and PUT. I would still go with making it more flexible for every operation.

Comment: well, I see the problem is a bit deeper than I thought. I don't really understand why there's no patch/partial update support in the spring. maybe I just don't know, will study it deeper. It might be not too difficult to implement. Will try. Thank you!